# adb devices hangs with Python, while it doesn't hang from command line

Tags: android, python-3.x, adb

I have a bluestacks emulator instance running at port 51510. As you can see in the image, I can connect to it from command line and call `adb devices` command:

[image]

I have tested clicking etc, it is working. But when I try to do it with Python with below code, it hangs at `adb.devices()` line.

```
from ppadb.client import Client

adb = Client(host='127.0.0.1', port=51510) #Stops on one of these two lines 
devices = adb.devices()
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please don't post screen shot of the terminal, just copy and paste the text content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ppadb is a pure Python adb client so it does not make use of adb executable and is designed to directly communicate with adb server (note that adb server is not adbd on Android side!).

adb server is also the service that manages the list of connected devices (-> adb server is the service that answers `adb devices` or `adb.devices()` requests).

```
adb client <-> adb server <-> adbd on Android device 1
                        ^ 
                        └---> adbd on Android device 2
```

By directly connecting to 127.0.0.1:51510 you even try to bypass the adb server which will not work as ppadb is designed to communicate with the adb server and not directly with the adbd on Android side. Therefore I would try to connect to adb server 127.0.0.1:5037 then it should work.